# Why do I get different output of the same code but on different laptops?

Tags: c, windows, unix, struct, compilation

So there is this code:

```
struct HT_Task
{
    int tid;                        /*Task's identifier*/
    int difficulty;                 /*Task's difficulty*/
    struct HT_Task *next;           /*Pointer to the next node*/
};

struct General_Tasks_HT
{
    int count;                      /*Count of tasks*/
    struct HT_Task *tasks[];         /*General tasks hash table*/
};

struct General_Tasks_HT general_tasks_ht; // global variable 

unsigned int max_tasks_g;
```

To allocate memory for the hash table I do the following:

```
    for( i=0; i<max_tasks_g; i++)
    {
        general_tasks_ht.tasks[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct HT_Task) * max_tasks_g);
    }
   
    for( i=0; i<max_tasks_g; i++)
    {
        general_tasks_ht.tasks[i] = NULL;
    }
```

The thing is, when I compile it and run it on a windows laptop it runs perfectly but on a mac laptop it gets segmentation fault in the for loop. Why is that happening and which is right?
(On mac the clang version is 12.0.0 and on windows MinGw 9.2.0)

Comment: Usually when that happens both compilers are right, and the code is wrong :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Undefined behavior (UB)**

`general_tasks_ht` has no memory for its [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) FAM `.tasks`, so assigning something to `general_tasks_ht.tasks[i]` is not defined.

---

Using a default initialized `struct` with a FAM is strange in global memory.

---

Instead, maybe a pointer to a `struct General_Tasks_HT`?

```
struct General_Tasks_HT *general_tasks_ht_p;

int main() {
  int n = 42;
  general_tasks_ht_p = malloc(sizeof *general_tasks_ht_p + 
    n * sizeof *(general_tasks_ht_p->tasks));

  general_tasks_ht_p->count = n;
  for (int i=0; i < general_tasks_ht_p->count; i++) {
      general_tasks_ht_p->tasks[i] = malloc(sizeof *(general_tasks_ht_p->tasks[i]));
  }
```